# flock call within function always 'succeeds', ignoring previous lock

Tags: php, locking

To prevent multiple instances of a PHP-based daemon I wrote from ever running simultaneously, I wrote a simple function to acquire a lock with [`flock`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.flock.php) when the process starts, and called it at the start of my daemon. A simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    function acquire_lock () {
        $file_handle = fopen('mylock.lock', 'w');
        $got_lock_successfully = flock($file_handle, LOCK_EX);
        if (!$got_lock_successfully) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected failure to acquire lock.");
        }
    }

    acquire_lock(); // Block until all other instances of the script are done...

    // ... then do some stuff, for example:
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo "Sleeping... $i\n";
        sleep(1);
    }

?>
```

When I execute the script above multiple times in parallel, the behaviour I *expect* to see - since the lock is never explicitly released throughout the duration of the script - is that the second instance of the script will wait until the first has completed before it proceeds past the `acquire_lock()` call. In other words, if I run this particular script in two parallel terminals, I expect to see one terminal count to 10 while the other waits, and then see the other count to 10.

This is not what happens. Instead, I see both scripts happily executing in parallel - the second script does *not* block and wait for the lock to be available.

As you can see, I'm checking the return value from `flock` and it is `true`, indicating that the (exclusive) lock has been acquired successfully. Yet this evidently isn't preventing another process from acquiring another 'exclusive' lock on the same file.

Why, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store the file pointer resource returned from [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) in a global variable. In the example given in the question, `$file_handle` is automatically destroyed upon going out of scope when `acquire_lock()` returns, and this releases the lock taken out by `flock`.

For example, here is a modified version of the script from the question which exhibits the desired behaviour (note that the only change is storing the file handle returned by `fopen` in a global):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    function acquire_lock () {
        global $lock_handle;
        $lock_handle = fopen('mylock.lock', 'w');
        $got_lock_successfully = flock($lock_handle, LOCK_EX);
        if (!$got_lock_successfully) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected failure to acquire lock.");
        }
    }

    acquire_lock(); // Block until all other instances of the script are done...

    // ... then do some stuff, for example:
    for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo "Sleeping... $i\n";
        sleep(1);
    }

?>
```

Note that this seems to be a bug in PHP. The changelog from the `flock` documentation states that in version 5.3.2:

> The automatic unlocking when the file's resource handle is closed was removed. Unlocking now always has to be done manually.

but at least for PHP 5.5, this is false; `flock` locks are released both by explicit calls to `fclose` and by the resource handle going out of scope.

I reported this as a bug in November 2014 and may update this question and answer pair if it is ever resolved. In case I get eaten by piranhas before then, you can check the bug report yourself to see if this behaviour has been fixed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68509